# Spring boot - using Freemarker to compose html mail body

Tags: spring-boot, html-email, freemarker

I'm currently using Spring Boot 1.2.5 with Spring MVC and Freemarker for web development.

I'd like to use freemarker templates to compose html mail body which will be sent with `JavaMailSender`.

Mail would be composed and sent from one of services.

What's easiest setup to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's relatively simple to use templates in custom way (it's possible to inject freemarkers Configuration from spring boot freemarker auto configurer):

```
import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;

//skipped class etc for clarity

@Autowired
private final Configuration freemarkerConfiguration;

public void process() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    final Template template = freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("/path/to/template.ftl");
    final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("param1", 1);
    params.put("param2", 2);

    template.process(params, /* use writer to which body will be written */);
}
```